# Using prepositions with time

Tags: prepositions, time

Which is the correct preposition?

- *at* evening
- *on* evening
- *in* the evening

Is this correct, and if so, which one:

> He mailed me (*on* evening / *in* the evening / *at* evening).

How are prepositions used with time?

Comment: This is a very broad question. There isn't a hard and fast rule; it's more a matter of imitating what other people do. Depending on context, you might also see "this evening", "of an evening", "around evening", ...

Comment: but i don't know how to use it, that is why i asked here. Anyway i think **in the evening** is more appropriate for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suhail.

In most cases you will use *in the evening* to refer to things in general. For instance:

I usually read a newspaper **in the evening**.

Charles enjoys a glass of wine **in the evening**.

In your case, I find it more appropriate to say:

He mailed me **yesterday evening**.

**Yesterday evening**, I received an e-mail from him.

Comment: Why do you say: "in most cases" and "refer to things in general"? Does it mean there are exceptions?

Comment: @Mari-Lou A : A more colloquial general usage is shown on Google: 'evenings, i go to a tutorial in parow...' (I've seen less dodgy examples too.) Obviously, 'yesterday / this / Monday... evening' are more specific usages.